# Why can't I update an input element inside click event?

Tags: javascript, html

Why does the input element not get updated?

```
function route() {
    let textfield = {
     inputEl: document.querySelector('#textfield'),
     setValue: function(str) {
        this.inputEl.value = str;
     }
   };

   textfield.inputEl.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
     document.body.innerHTML += '<button id="select">Select</button>';
     owner(textfield);
   });
}

function owner(controller) {
  document.querySelector('#select').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      controller.setValue("Hello Universe!");
  });
}

route();
```

I know how to go around this problem but i prefer to use `controller.setValue()` to update the input.

Comment: do you see any errors in console? if so, what do they say?

Comment: There is no errors in console

Comment: can you describe better what you intend to do with this line: `document.querySelector('#select', function(event) {...});` - as far as I can tell, `.querySelector(...)` does not take a second parameter

Comment: Please include your html too, all relevant code. What does `setValue()` do?

Comment: html only has one element which is input element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

I have updated the code below - hopefully this is closer to what you are trying to achieve.

I needed to add a container where to place the button (instead of adding it to the `body`) - so added a wrapper container like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="text" id="textfield" />
</div>
```

Then, we can append the button to it as a child, like this:

```
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(btn);
```

**See updated code below**

```js
function route() {
  let textfield = {
    inputEl: document.querySelector('#textfield'),
    setValue: function(str) {
      this.inputEl.value = str;
    }
  };

  textfield.inputEl.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // add the button if it's not already in there
    if(document.getElementById('select')){
      return;
    }
    
    let btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.id = 'select';
    btn.innerHTML = 'Select';


    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(btn);
    owner(textfield);
  });
}

function owner(controller) {
  document.getElementById('select').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    controller.setValue("Hello Universe!");
  });
}

route();
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input type="text" id="textfield" />
</div>
```

Comment: I want when i click on the input, the button should be appended and when i click on button the input must be updated!

Comment: it's works when i remove controller.setValue function and replace it with document.querySelector("#textfield").value = "Hello Universe!";

Comment: @AymanBenyahia based on your comment, I updated my answer - see if it helps

Comment: what do you think the problem is? is it `innerHTML` should i use `appendChild` instead? if so why is that ?

Comment: I think it's related to using `innerHTML` on the `body` tag (which is not good practice) - this _trick_ might work on smaller pages but if you have a large page, with lots of HTML elements, it starts to break the structure of the page (since you are always appending at the end of the `body` and not in a specific location)

Comment: but also this line makes no sense `document.querySelector('#select', function(event) {
      controller.setValue("Hello Universe!");
  });` - as I mentioned before, `.querySelector` only takes one parameter and you are not adding a listener to the newly added button (see my code on how I add one to it)

Comment: Oh XD, i did not see it

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, the problem is `innerHTML` because it removes old markup and add new one which removes any event listener that was set it them.

Comment: as far as I can tell, it does not remove mark up but adds to it (i.e. `+=`) - however, it does add the same thing over and over